# SWIFT: detect touch outside current view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitouch

This is a relatively simple problem.  I have a tableViewController which appears after the user presses a button, but it doesn't cover the entire screen, leaving some of the previous view controller visible.  I was trying to use touchesEnded to dismiss the tableViewController, when the touchLocation.x property (the x coordinate of the CGPoint location of the touch) was past a certain point.  Problem is, when the touch is past the x point (outside of the tableViewController), touchesEnded doesn't actually receive anything or get called, because it's outside the view, so my dismiss function doesn't get called.  Does anyone know how to detect a touch outside of the current view, so that any touch outside the current view dismisses the said current view? Thanks

Comment: Cover the entire screen with a view whose background color is clear, so there is something there to receive the touch.

Comment: The problem is, I use a custom slide in transition, where I set the width of the vc to 0.7 the normal width, so won't any clear view I add into the tableViewController also be a part of that 0.7 widtht? Also, when you add a view to the tableview, it makes it into a sort of cell

Comment: I don't see how that matters. The _table view_ can be 0.7 the normal width, while there is still a invisible view around it to pick up the touches.

Comment: How do I set the tableview in a tableViewController to only be 0.7 of the entire view?

Comment: You would need it to be the child of another view controller. Either that or use a normal view controller, not a table view controller.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but I am trying to do what you said, I put a view with a clear background, and I still get a white background instead of the view controller under the current one, do you know why?

Comment: No, I don't. But then, I can't see your current code. — The point I am making is simply that the concept "detect a touch outside of a view" is nonsense. A view _is_ what you touch; that is really _all_ a view is, it is a way of giving a layer touchability. You cannot touch somewhere and expect it to be detected unless what you are touching is a view. So I'm saying: to detect a touch, put a view.

Comment: yea I got that point, I just realized that a clear view just shows the white background of the original view controller, so I can't see the vc behind that one anymore if you know how to make that visible, I'd appreciate it, if not, oh well lol

Comment: nevermind, I figure out what I needed, thanks for your help tho

Comment: I provided complete demo code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a clear view behind the table view, covering the screen, that can detect the tap outside the table view.

There seems to be some difficulty grasping the general concept of how to do this, so here is a simple demonstration of the basic principle. This is a *complete* project; just copy it all and paste it right into a fresh vanilla project's view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Present", for: .normal)
        b.sizeToFit()
        b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tap), for: .touchUpInside)
        b.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        self.view.addSubview(b)
    }
    @objc func tap() {
        self.present(VC2(), animated: true)
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        let tgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tgr)
        let child = VC3()
        self.addChild(child)
        self.view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
        child.view.frame.size.width = 0.7*self.view.bounds.width
        child.view.frame.size.height = 0.7*self.view.bounds.height
        child.view.center = CGPoint(x:self.view.bounds.midX, y:self.view.bounds.midY)
        child.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
    }
    @objc func tap() {
        print("farewell")
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

class VC3: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .green
        let tgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tgr)
    }
    @objc func tap() {
        print("ouch, stop that")
    }
}
```

Run the project and you will see a yellow view with a Present button; tap the Present button. A green view appears floating in the middle of the screen; notice that the yellow view is still visible behind it (that is part of your goal). Pretend that that is the table view. If you tap it, that tap is detected by VC3, which is our substitute for your table view controller. But if you tap outside it, the whole thing is dismissed (that is the other part of your goal).